# Using Syncfusion SfDatagrid,problem with ColumnSizer

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I'm using a syncfusion SfDatagrid in a WPF application and I have a problem with the columns width. Here's my xmal:

```xml
     <sc:SfDataGrid x:Name="Ventes_Det_Dt"
                                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                   AllowFiltering="False"
                                   Background="White"
                                   ColumnSizer="Auto"
                                   Foreground="Black" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1">
                            <sc:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                                <sc:GridTextColumn HeaderText="ARTICLE" MappingName="art"/>
                                <sc:GridTextColumn HeaderText="LIBELLE" MappingName="lib"/>
                                <sc:GridTextColumn HeaderText="QTE" MappingName="qte"/>
                                <sc:GridTextColumn HeaderText="POIDS NET" MappingName="pds"/>
                            </sc:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                        </sc:SfDataGrid>
```

Has you can see the Column Sizer is set to "Auto" which means (for me) that all the columns are fit to their contents. But this is not the case, look:
[image]

You can see that the content of the column ARTICLE and LIBELLE are cut on the right.

Can someone helps me?

Comment: ColumnSizer calculates column width based on MinWidth and MaxWidth properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to change the MaxWidth Property of the SfDataGrid but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted the reported scenario with the provided details. The ColumnSizing was applied properly as expected. Here, I have attached a tested sample for your reference.

**Sample link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfDataGrid_Demo240254668

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see that it is working. In my application the SfdataGrid ItemsSource comes from Entity FrameWork query and not from an ObservableCollection, so my question is : Can this be the problem ??

Comment: I forgot 1 thing  : I'm using a trial version of SyncFusion WPF , this can be the problem two ?